# Play framework not using all 64 cores

Tags: concurrency, playframework, akka

How do I make Play framework use all the 64 cores on the machine. No matter whatever I configure, I could not make my Play webapp use all the 64 cores. Is there a specific setting that I should focus on? Please help!

Currently, I have the following configured:

```
play {
  akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 10.0
          parallelism-max = 64
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

internal-threadpool-size=64
iteratee-threadpool-size=64
```

When I look at the machine processes, I could see that only one third of the processor cores are utilized. Is there any other setting that I could do so that all 64 cores are used?

What we have is a WebSocket endpoint in one of our Play controller in a non blocking mode uisng the WebSocket.Async call. To load test this WebSocket endpoint, I have a simple client that uses Akka to dynamically create multiple Actor instances. Each of those Actor instance creates a new WebSocket connection and sends a couple of thousands of messages.

Both the number of messages that will be sent via a single WebSocket connection and the total number of Actor instances are configurable. This way, I can really load test my WebSocket endpoint exposed by the Play framework.

But no matter whatever I do, I do not see the server utilizing all of its cores. This literally slows down our performance. Any suggestions on which configuration in the Play framework could be tweaked to make sure that all the 64 cores are used during heavy load?

Here is what I see when Play framework loads up (from the log file):

```
play {
  # merge of application.conf: 7,reference.conf: 8
  akka {
    # application.conf: 9
    loglevel=WARNING
    # application.conf: 8
    "event-handlers"=[
      # application.conf: 8
      "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"
    ]
    # merge of application.conf: 10,reference.conf: 12
    actor {
      # application.conf: 11
      "default-dispatcher" {
        # application.conf: 13
        "fork-join-executor" {
          # application.conf: 15
          "parallelism-factor"=2
          # application.conf: 14
          "parallelism-min"=8
          # application.conf: 16
          "parallelism-max"=256
        }
        # application.conf: 12
        executor="fork-join-executor"
      }
      # reference.conf: 13
      retrieveBodyParserTimeout="1 second"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the use of importing the following statement in my Play controller?  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual used number of threads is parallelism-factor * availableProcessors bounded by min and max. As per the documentation:

"      # This will be used if you have set "executor = "fork-join-executor""
      fork-join-executor {
        # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
        parallelism-min = 8

```
    # The parallelism factor is used to determine thread pool size using the
    # following formula: ceil(available processors * factor). Resulting size
    # is then bounded by the parallelism-min and parallelism-max values.
    parallelism-factor = 3.0

    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-max = 64
  }
```

" - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/general/configuration.html

Comment: You mean to say with parallelism-factor = 3.0 and parallelism-max = 64, I could use all my 64 cores?

Comment: When I query for the Runtime available processors, I get to see 64. But only one third of them is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling Akka that each processor can have 10 threads but capping the total number of threads at 64.

You can lower the `parallelism-factor` or raise the `parallelism-max` (obviously doing load testing to see which one actually performs better for your app).

Comment: What influence does the parallelism-factor indicate? How does lowering it would make use of all the 64 cores?

Comment: @user3102968 If you lower it to 1.0, for example, then each processor will only use one thread. Since you have a max of 64 threads available, if the load on your app requires it then you would be using all 64 cores.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation. I in fact referred to that before I configured my application.config file. I originally had the parallelism-factor set to 1 and the parallelism-max set to 64, but I did not see that all my 64 cores were used. I just kept adding more and more load. By load, I mean I have a WebSocket end point on the Play server and I called it multiple times with each WebSocket connection handling thousands and thousands of requests.

Comment: Is there any other idea to figure out why all my cores are not utilized?

Comment: I don't know anything about how Play handles WebSockets. Hopefully someone else has some thoughts on this. You should probably edit your question to include which version of Play you're using and how you're testing. The info the more likely you are to get a response.